# Express.js no recibo la cookie en el navegador

Tags: nodejs, express, http, cookies, setcookie

**tengo un server en express donde seteo una cookie para autenticar un usuario, pero la cookie no aparece**

cuando voy al navegador y abro la devtools, en la pestaña "application" entro a cookies y no me aparece ninguna como se ve a continuación :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una porción del codigo donde seteo la cookie:

```
    const cookies = {
      expires: new Date(Date.now()+process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
      httpOnly: true
    }

    res.cookie('jwt', token, cookies)

    return res
      .status(200)
      .json({user: user.email, loged: true})
```

Si hago la petición con postman, si me aparece la cookie(en postman)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Aunque te parezca buena idea poner una imagen del código en la pregunta o respuesta, no lo es. No todos pueden ver las imágenes y es muy tedioso tener que transcribir el código para tratar de reproducir el problema. [es.so] es un sitio de código y no de imágenes. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta, tanto en la pregunta como en la respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Gracias al siguiente post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978720/res-cookie-is-not-setting-cookie-in-chrome-browser

En el fetch que hago en el front hay que agregar lo siguiente:

```
credentials: "include",
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los headers permitir el acceso del localhost:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y ahi esta la cookie**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]